# Rust gettext_ng did not work with variables. How to make it work?

Tags: rust

I try to translate a litte Rust code at runtime. But I get a compile error:

```
println!("{}", catalog.gettext("\nThe weather in {}", city));

34  |     println!("{}", catalog.gettext("\nThe weather in {}", city)); 
    |                            ^^^^^^^                      ------
    |                                                         | |
    |                                                         | unexpected argument of type `std::string::String`
    |                                                         help: remove the extra argument
    |
```

How to make that it works?

If I do it without variables then it works:

```
println!("{}", catalog.gettext("\nThe weather in"));
```

When run with German environment (`export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`), the output is: `Das Wetter in`

I would like to get the Output: `Das Wetter in Koeln`

Comment: By "mask", do you mean "make"?

Comment: It looks like `gettext` does not take the arguments you think it does.

Comment: What is `catalog`?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
println!("{} {}",catalog.get_text("the weather in"), city)
```

Comment: Why? Please actually explain the code and don't just add a snippet.